# Drawable center-crop with XML

Tags: android, xml, splash-screen, android-drawable

I want to put an image as a launch screen. Since I don't want to use a layout to do that (that would make useless to use a launch screen because of launch time) I want to put a `windowBackground` using an `xml` drawable.

Unfortunately I cannot find anything able to emulate the ImageView `CENTER_CROP` inside a drawable and the "**bitmap**" `xml` tag seems not having that property.

Since I cannot execute any code (because of the origin of the launch screen that must be immediate), I am wondering if it is possible to define a new `xml` to put in a drawable `xml` file. In that way, I could develop a new `XML Drawable` to achieve the result.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem with setting the windowBackground through XML as well and came across your post.  I know this is pretty old now, but just in case someone else comes across your question, have you seen the "clip" options in the gravity setting?

```
android:gravity=["top" | "bottom" | "left" | "right" | "center_vertical" |
                      "fill_vertical" | "center_horizontal" | "fill_horizontal" |
                      "center" | "fill" | "clip_vertical" | "clip_horizontal"]
```

Here's a link: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Bitmap